# Black Screen after boot, no command working, not even terminal

Tags: boot, screen

I have Ubuntu with latest KDE on a Lenovo Z570 with Optimus.

I've installed drivers and bumblebee, both integrated and nVidia cards are working perfect (not the issue).

I have a RAT 9 Wirless mouse, which I tried to configure and this is the problem.

I needed to edit `Xorg.conf` in order to make it work. But apparently, I did not have any file `Xorg.conf` in either `/etc/X11`  or  `/usr/share/X11`. By the way, `Xorg.conf` or `Xorg.conf.d`? I've looked for both but I've found none.

So I created the folder `Xorg.conf.d` in `/etc/X11/Xorg.conf.d/` and created the file `910-rat.conf`, where I created the `Section "InputClass"` with the `Identifier`, `Product`, `Button Mapping` and everything. Saved, rebooted, got stuck.

**Normal Boot:**

After the boot logo (5 charging dots) I get the Black Screen.
I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, I've tried editing the startup parameters in Grub, with `nomodeset` instead of `quiet splash`, and the `init=/bin/bash` trick ... but to no avail.

**Recovery mode:**

Stuck at:

```
[2.315147] Freeing unused kernel memory
Loading, please wait...
[2.32...] udevd[108]:starting version 175
[2.35...] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet ...
...(some more pci and eth0)
[2.359..] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[2.36...] pci ... PCI INT A -> GSI 16(level, low) ->IRQ 16
[2.370..] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFO VGA - removing generic driver
```

and that's it...

I just found out drivers from nVidia are not recommended, I don't remember if I installed from nvidia or xswap...something repo, or both.
But what do I do now? I would prefer not to reinstall Ubuntu, as my KDE setting took me like a week to set, and I don't know where they are stored, as I don't have a `Xorg.conf` file. Why don't I have it?